# Why is this nav not perfectly centered?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, in the following fiddle the nav is not perfectly centered. It's not by much, maybe 3 mm on my monitor, but it has been bugging me why.

http://jsfiddle.net/RMBs6/

Here's a snippet of what I think might be the problematic code (but check the fiddle out too/first):

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3em;
    width: 940px;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It is centered. But it is centering based on the `width` you specified for the `wrapper`. Just changed `940px` to `500px` and it worked nicely here.

Comment: @wendelbsilva indeed, you're right had to write the same.

Comment: It's not centered.  The `<ul>` has about 5 pixels more space to the left of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block` will mean that your items aren't 'flush' against each other. So having a background will really show this up.  I presume that's why you've used the -4px margin on the `<a>`.

**Option 1 - display: inline-block**

If you must use `display: inline-block` then I'd suggest removing the -4px on the `<a>` and using `margin: 0 -2px` on the li.  That will bring it in on both sides.  You can see this working here (note that I took the liberty of making the border only 1 pixel):

http://jsfiddle.net/RMBs6/6/

**Option 2 - float**

Using float will make the list items flush next to each other.  However, using `text-align: center` on the container won't make it centered now.  You'll need to define a width and use `margin: 0 auto`.

**Option 3 - display: table**

This is my favourite option.  It's a way of making the list items fit perfectly in the container.  You won't need to define a width (px or %) on the list items, or the child  items.  They behave like cells in a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/RMBs6/7/

---

*To show the initial problem clearer (as I understand it), here's a beautiful picture.*

[image]

Comment: that _is_ why I used the -4px. It worked at the time. Also, on my computer it's the left side that is larger, while on yours (from what i understand from the beautiful picture) the right side is?

Comment: It worked at the time but it isn't working now? On my picture the left side is bigger. The red is highlighting the additional part that's missing to make it equal.  Or, if you like, you need to take the red width away from the left side.

Comment: It worked at the time (I now realize) because the nav did not need to be centered (it was left-aligned). And I realize the width now, yes, it's the same on my computer. The red section was a little ambiguous.

Comment: While we're at it, why use float instead of inline-block?

Comment: Using float will make the list items sit flush next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 .navigation ul 
{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is centered. But it is centering based on the `width` you specified for the wrapper. Just changed `940px` to `500px` and it worked nicely here.

If you really want something that work everytime, you can use `%`.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gPXms/):

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a max-width on your wrapper

```
.wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 3em;
            max-width: 940px;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

well as far as I can see, it's not centered about 4px: the 4px you set as negative margin for every link

margin-right: -4px;

getting rid of it and using another method than display:inline-block (float for example) or just remove any white space and line breaks between the list items will do it.